# AsyncTasks are too slow for several simultaneous networking operations

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm developing an app which must heavily interact with the server.

So user input name and password and after authorization the next tasks must be performed:

1. The app has to fetch all incoming and outcoming messages for this user and load them to SQLite database.
2. Fetch all user friends (JSON with id,names,contact_data) and also load it to the app's database
3. Jump to the next activity and display income messages from the local database.

   The problem this operations are too slow and when app starts new activity it is nothing to fetch from the database :AsyncTasks have not completed yet.I'm forced to use AsyncTask.get() in order to wait when they all complete but this takes over 16 seconds to wait!

   So what should I do: use threads, or before loading fetched data to database hold it in memory and display it in the new activity instead of fetching it from the database?But even without database tasks other fetching tasks take nearly 10 seconds to wait!So what should I do?

Comment: Have you thought about doing a really fast get to retrieve information to be displayed to the user, while other operations are still operating in the background? This is a tactic used by many mobile apps in order to increase the *appearance* of low latency.

Comment: How much time does it take to execute one task ? How many tasks execute in parallel ?

Comment: @DeepakBala There are 7 tasks and i use .get() for all of them...

Comment: @Perception Please can you explain this in more details?

Comment: @HarryCater How much time does each task take on average ? Is the number '10 seconds' the average time ?

Comment: @DeepakBala from 2 to 3 seconds.Fetching data is the most continuous - 5 seconds.

Comment: Best option is to do this in the background while the UI shows a spinner or progress indicated for them until it's ready ONLY if the data is required to use the app or activity. And yes either use AsyncTask or a thread. DO NOT use a service for this, as per Google developer doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oke a couple of things going pretty wrong here.

1. Do not use AsyncTasks for Networking. Use a service. In short, this is because your AsyncTask will stop, as soon as the Activity that started it will stop. This means that network requests get aborted easily and data goes lost and has to re-start again when the Activity is opened again.
2. Do not use .get() on AsyncTasks. This makes the UI thread wait for the task to complete, making the whole AsyncTask idea kinda useless. In other words: This blocks your UI.

What you should do:

1. Read up on using services. You can also have a look at a great opensource library called RoboSpice to help you with this.
2. Stop using .get() on AsyncTasks, if you want to know when it is done just use a listener.
3. Execute AsyncTasks on a threadpool ( myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR); ) when possible.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. Per google: "If you need to perform work outside your main thread, but only while the user is interacting with your application, then you should probably instead create a new thread and not a service."

Services in this case buy him nothing as they still run on the application main thread. See [Android Developer - Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: @LeifAshley I do not think it is. You're neglecting the difference between 'work' and specifically networking. If you'd read the next line in your quote, you would see: " For example, if you want to play some music, but only while your activity is running ".  There are 2 important differences here to note: Playing music is not networking;  and 'while your activity is running'. 
Simply because he is not uploading any data, does not mean that it is ok if all the networking progress gets lost whenever the Activity gets destroyed.

Comment: @LeifAshley Note that an Activity gets destroyed not only when the user leaves the app or the current screen, but also if (s)he per example rotates the device. When using an AsyncTask for pulling in your data, your app will have to start all over again, resulting in longer loading times. Even if the user decides to leave your app for some reason, you might still want to finish the network request. 
You should look into the advantages of using a SyncAdapter (which also runs a service and is recommended for syncing data both ways with a server) or libraries like RoboSpice which handle the same.

Comment: @LeifAshley And of course, he will have to create a thread within the Service, but that's a whole different subject.

Comment: You said "Do not use AsyncTasks for Networking. Use a service." which is incorrect as per the specs of the service contract and as per Google's own advice. Google literally said, don't do that.
Then you said, "In short, this is because your AsyncTask will stop, as soon as the Activity that started it will stop." - this too is 100% incorrect. An AsyncTask is a thread and it is not tied directly to an Activity. If you have a service class that spawns the activity for your app, like a singleton, then obviously the AsycTask doesn't just disappear if the activity if killed...

Comment: Whether you use an AsyncTask or service to pull the data, neither of these are tied to an Activity from creation or rotation/reload. That's just poor app design. If the user leaves your app, and you have an AsyncTask, it will finish regardless of whether the app is in the foreground or not. Android doesn't pause your app, it just tiggers pause() in the lifecycle which is not suspending your app.

Comment: In short, you should never use a service because you need to do networking. It was not designed for that... I trust Google when they say, don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Service. This way it always can complete the tasks it was doing and you can complete all your tasks. Besides that you should initialize the app once, and after that only update the data.. that can't take 10 seconds.. than you're having an other problem.. But the nice thing of the service is that this can run in the background.  see: [Services in Android Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

== Edit

Also take a look at [GreenDao](http://greendao-orm.com) This library arranges fast SQlLite operations. Without the large setup!

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks are not meant to run several small tasks concurrently at the same time. Quoting the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

Use `Thread`s in a `ThreadPool` when you want to run multiple tasks concurrently.

How you want to handle this situation is up to you. When the background tasks take too long, you can always show an alert dialog to the user and then take them to the activity once the data has been populated. Many apps show a 'Loading' screen when this happens. You can also show the 'Loading' `Spinner` control if no data is available yet. Never show a blank screen.

If the server side calls are under your control, employ some sort of caching to speed up the time. Any API call that lasts more than a second will make for an impatient user. If not employ one of the   techniques mentioned in the previous paragraph. @Perception's technique is also one to consider if you can do it.